# Private task in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

In sharepoint Services 3 what is the best way to let people create a private task so that only they and the person that assigned it may see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is with Item Level permissions.  You can restrict access to just specific users.  However this will be a management nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that item level premission will be a management nightmare. You'll need to create different lists (for example: a list for each employee).

If there is only one task assigner (one manager for example) or realtively few, than you can create a simple list and configure it to display each user only his on item.
Notice, however, that this way you'll have to make twists, so that new tasks will be created from the employee's user.
And give the manager full control on that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a workflow that automatically fires on creation; change the permission then.

Answer (score 0):

I work on SharePoint and am the program manager for permissions management.

I'd discourage you from manually setting item level permissions, as someone posted - this would be a management nightmare, your best bet is either workflow or custom code that sets permissions after an item is updated.

Alternatively, if the creator-assigner relationship is pretty static, then it might be wise to create lists along those lines, that you could then permission accordingly. Note that doing this you'd lose the ability to easily view tasks across multiple creators/assignees.